# My Character arms intersect and overlap with the body. How to fix it?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]
Arms are intersecting with the Body,They belong to the same object mesh. How can I fix this. I tryed to make it rigid body and it didn't change at all. Did some research couldn't find any answer. Im clearly new in blender, so I might not even know exactly what to search for in order to find an answer. Hope someone can help me.
Cheers.

Comment: you're supposed to avoid it with the keyframes you're going to create for your armature

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have mentioned that I imported a couple of animations from mixamo and combined them. Let's say I want the clown to clap his hands or play "percussion" with his hands on his belly. I was wondering if  there'e was a way of blender stoping the meshes from intersecting and  going across  each other.

Comment: not that I know, you need to fix that with the bones so that meshes don't penetrate

Comment: Thanks moonboots

Comment: Hi did you find out how to fix the above problem? I'm also experiencing the same thing.

Comment: @moonboots so there's no "automatic" solution you just need to make sure on the animations it doesn't cross over into the mesh?

Comment: Exactly...................